# ForkJoinPool: clean up thread locals

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

I would like to use a scala parallel collection framework. Each thread is supposed to execute some logic that uses values from thread local. To be able to achieve that, I am using InheritableThreadLocal. This way, all threads in ForkJoinPool have access to thread locals from parent thread. My question is if after executing the task, thread locals are cleaned up? If not, how can I reset them before they are used by other tasks?

Comment: ForkJoinTasks are serviced by an arbitrary thread in the pool, and child tasks are not run by child threads. Also, threads may be created on any submit. So it's not obvious to me what the goal is. However, Java 8 offers `CountedCompleter` to simplify `onComplete` style clean-up. Is that what you mean?